# Error when trying decompress byte array ( C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, indexoutofboundsexception, compression

I am trying to decompress byte array into a bitmap. but getting error.
This my coding....when execute it produce the error that "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    private static byte[] minbuffer;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x83,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x1B,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE,0x7B,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFC,0xF9,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xBF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF9,0xF9,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x87,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF9,0xF9,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFB,0xF9,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC3,0xF9,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF8,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC3,0xF9,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF8,0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC3,0xF9,0xFC,0xFF,0xE3,0xFF,0xFF,0xC3,0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xE7,0xFB,0xC0,0x07,0x83,0xFF,0xFE,0x1F,0x1F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xE7,0xF3,0x1F,0xF3,0x07,0xFF,0xF0,0xFF,0xCF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xE3,0xF4,0x7F,0xF8,0x6F,0xFF,0x87,0xFF,0xE7,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xE3,0xE1,0xFF,0xF8,0xCF,0xFE,0x3F,0xFF,0xF3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF3,0xE3,0xFF,0xF0,0x9F,0xF0,0xFF,0xFF,0xF9,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF3,0xC7,0xFF,0xC6,0xBF,0xC3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF3,0xCF,0xFF,0x9E,0x3E,0x1F,0xFF,0xFF,0xF6,0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF9,0x9F,0xFF,0x3E,0x78,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC7,0x1F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF9,0x3F,0xFE,0x7E,0x78,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE,0x0F,0xCF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFD,0x7F,0xFC,0xFC,0xF0,0xF7,0xFF,0xF8,0x3F,0xE7,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFC,0xFF,0xF9,0xF8,0xF8,0xF7,0xFF,0xE0,0xFF,0xF9,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFC,0xFF,0xF3,0xF1,0xFC,0x77,0xFF,0x81,0xFF,0xFC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE,0x7F,0xE7,0xF1,0xFC,0x13,0xFE,0x33,0xFF,0xFE,0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE,0x7F,0x9F,0xC3,0xF8,0xC1,0xF8,0xC7,0xFE,0x1F,0x1F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,0xBF,0x9B,0xF0,0xF0,0x03,0x9F,0xF8,0xFF,0xCF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x3E,0x3F,0x33,0xF4,0xF7,0x8E,0x3F,0xE3,0xFF,0xE7,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xBC,0xFE,0x73,0xE4,0xF6,0x3C,0xFF,0x82,0x00,0x03,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x99,0xFC,0xFB,0xCE,0xE0,0xF9,0xFE,0x20,0x1F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xCB,0xF1,0xFB,0x1E,0x63,0xF3,0xF8,0x07,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC3,0xE3,0xFC,0x7F,0x0F,0xE7,0xC0,0xCF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC7,0xCF,0xFF,0xFE,0x3F,0xE0,0x0F,0x9F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xEF,0x9F,0xFF,0xF8,0xFF,0xE0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xEE,0x3F,0xFF,0xF1,0xFF,0x0F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xE0,0xFF,0xFF,0xC7,0xF8,0x3F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF3,0xFF,0xFF,0x9F,0xE1,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE,0x3E,0x0F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFC,0xF0,0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF1,0xC3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC6,0x1F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x90,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFE,0x03,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFC,0x3F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xE3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF };
      buffer = decompress(buffer, 168, 44);
      Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static byte[] decompress(byte[] raw, int width, int height)
    {
        byte[] signdecompress = new byte[width * height];
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w < (width / 8); w++)
                {
                    byte num = raw[h * (width / 8) + w];
                    int ByteIndex = (h * width + w * 8);
                    string str = Convert.ToString(num);
                    for (byte s = 0; s < 8; s++)
                    {
                        if (str[s] == '1')
                        {

                            signdecompress[ByteIndex + s] = (byte)(255);
                        }
                        else
                            signdecompress[ByteIndex + s] = (byte)(0);
                    }

                }

            }

        return signdecompress;
    }
  }
}
```

please help. i need the result to become

```
0xFF,0xD8,0xFF,0xE0,0x00,0x10,0x4A,0x46,0x49,0x46,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xDB,0x00,0x43,0x00,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x01,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x03,0x02,0x02,0x03,0x03,0x06,0x04,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x07,0x05,0x05,0x04,0x06,0x08,0x07,0x09,0x08,0x08,0x07,0x08,0x08,0x09,0x0A,0x0D,0x0B,0x09,0x0A,0x0C,0x0A,0x08,0x08,0x0B,0x0F,0x0B,0x0C,0x0D,0x0E,0x0E,0x0F,0x0E,0x09,0x0B,0x10,0x11,0x10,0x0E,0x11,0x0D,0x0E,0x0E,0x0E,0xFF,0xC0,0x00,0x0B,0x08,0x00,0x2C,0x00,0xA8,0x01,0x01,0x11,0x00,0xFF,0xC4,0x00,0x1F,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x05,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0A,0x0B,0xFF,0xC4,0x00,0xB5,0x10,0x00,0x02,0x01,0x03,0x03,0x02,0x04,0x03,0x05,0x05,0x04,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x7D,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x00,0x04,0x11,0x05,0x12,0x21,0x31,0x41,0x06,0x13,0x51,0x61,0x07,0x22,0x71,0x14,0x32,0x81,0x91,0xA1,0x08,0x23,0x42,0xB1,0xC1,0x15,0x52,0xD1,0xF0,0x24,0x33,0x62,0x72,0x82,0x09,0x0A,0x16,0x17,0x18,0x19,0x1A,0x25,0x26,0x27,0x28,0x29,0x2A,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39,0x3A,0x43,0x44,0x45,0x46,0x47,0x48,0x49,0x4A,0x53,0x54,0x55,0x56,0x57,0x58,0x59,0x5A,0x63,0x64,0x65,0x66,0x67,0x68,0x69,0x6A,0x73,0x74,0x75,0x76,0x77,0x78,0x79,0x7A,0x83,0x84,0x85,0x86,0x87,0x88,0x89,0x8A,0x92,0x93,0x94,0x95,0x96,0x97,0x98,0x99,0x9A,0xA2,0xA3,0xA4,0xA5,0xA6,0xA7,0xA8,0xA9,0xAA,0xB2,0xB3,0xB4,0xB5,0xB6,0xB7,0xB8,0xB9,0xBA,0xC2,0xC3,0xC4,0xC5,0xC6,0xC7,0xC8,0xC9,0xCA,0xD2,0xD3,0xD4,0xD5,0xD6,0xD7,0xD8,0xD9,0xDA,0xE1,0xE2,0xE3,0xE4,0xE5,0xE6,0xE7,0xE8,0xE9,0xEA,0xF1,0xF2,0xF3,0xF4,0xF5,0xF6,0xF7,0xF8,0xF9,0xFA,0xFF,0xDA,0x00,0x08,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x3F,0x00,0xFD,0xFB,0xA2,0x8A,0x28,0xAF,0x90,0x3F,0x68,0x9F,0x8E,0xFA,0x8E,0x99,0xE2,0x2F,0x0A,0xFC,0x0B,0xF8,0x17,0xE3,0x0F,0x0A,0xDC,0x7E,0xD0,0x7E,0x30,0xF1,0x55,0xB7,0x87,0xE5,0xB6,0x93,0x55,0xB4,0xBA,0xD4,0x3C,0x1B,0x65,0x2D,0xA4,0xD7,0xB7,0x5A,0xDC,0x9A,0x6B,0xC8,0xA6,0x6F,0x22,0xD6,0x13,0x22,0x45,0x21,0x55,0x76,0x92,0x2F,0xBF,0x91,0x14,0x9F,0x38,0x7C,0x57,0xF8,0x31,0xF0,0xC3,0xF6,0x45,0xF1,0x9F,0xEC,0x91,0xE2,0xDF,0x85,0xBE,0x10,0xB5,0xD4,0x7E,0x20,0xEB,0xDF,0xB4,0x56,0x95,0xA4,0x78,0x93,0xC6,0x9E,0x29,0x92,0x4D,0x4F,0x5D,0xD6,0x86,0xAF,0xA7,0x5F,0x58,0x5F,0xCF,0x71,0x7A,0xED,0xE6,0x6F,0x93,0xCC,0x37,0x1B,0x14,0xAC,0x1E,0x7F,0xCF,0xE5,0x75,0x07,0xF5,0x3A,0x8A,0x28,0xA2,0xBE,0x00,0xF1,0xEF,0xED,0x99,0xE2,0x9F,0xD9,0xD7,0xF6,0x8E,0x6D,0x03,0xF6,0xA6,0xF8,0x51,0xFF,0x00,0x08,0x3F,0xC1,0x9D,0x4F,0x55,0xD4,0x2D,0xFC,0x2F,0xF1,0x87,0xC3,0x77,0xF2,0x6A,0xBA,0x6D,0xD6,0x09,0xB8,0xB3,0xB7,0xBA,0xB1,0x8E,0x26,0xB8,0xB5,0x98,0xDB,0x7E,0xED,0x8F,0xCD,0xBE,0x78,0x65,0x68,0xD3,0xC9,0xDC,0xF1,0x7D,0xFF,0x00,0x45,0x14,0x51,0x45,0x14,0x51,0x45,0x14,0x51,0x5F,0x94,0x3E,0x3A,0xF8,0x7F,0xA1,0x78,0x1F,0xFE,0x0E,0xD1,0xF8,0x1D,0xF1,0x0A,0xE3,0xC0,0x1F,0x6B,0x87,0xE2,0x57,0x80,0x35,0x2B,0x7B,0x0D,0x7B,0xFB,0x71,0xD3,0xEC,0xFA,0xED,0x85,0x94,0xCB,0x71,0x73,0xE4,0x6E,0x3B,0xB1,0xA6,0xAD,0xAD,0xAF,0x96,0x55,0x22,0x3F,0x69,0xF3,0x06,0x64,0x8D,0xAB,0xA0,0xFD,0xAA,0x3E,0x29,0x7F,0xC2,0x79,0xFF,0x00,0x05,0x57,0xFD,0x9E,0x7F,0x66,0xFF,0x00,0x03,0xFC,0x3F,0xFF,0x00,0x85,0xBD,0xE2,0x6F,0x05,0xEA,0xB1,0x7C,0x45,0xD6,0x34,0xC8,0xEF,0xBE,0xC7,0x69,0xA7,0xDE,0xC5,0xFB,0x8D,0x39,0xAF,0xF5,0x08,0xA5,0x66,0xD3,0xE1,0xB7,0x4B,0x99,0xAF,0xA4,0x0D,0x6B,0x33,0x4A,0x46,0x9D,0x0A,0x23,0x7D,0xAC,0xD7,0xBF,0xCD,0xF0,0x1B,0xE3,0xAF,0xC4,0x7F,0x85,0x9A,0x8D,0xA7,0xC6,0x2F,0xDA,0x9B,0xC5,0x5E,0x14,0xD5,0xB5,0x7F,0xB3,0xC9,0x73,0xA5,0x7C,0x17,0xB2,0xB2,0xF0,0xFE,0x9F,0xA4,0xEC,0x8E,0x12,0xD0,0x5B,0x5E,0x5C,0xDB,0xDC,0xEA,0x4F,0xFB,0xF8,0xE4,0x63,0x37,0xDA,0x23,0xF3,0x16,0x4D,0xBE,0x54,0x6B,0x94,0xAF,0x9C,0x3F,0x68,0x9F,0xDA,0x3B,0xC6,0xFF,0x00,0xB2,0x87,0xC4,0xCD,0x2A,0x5F,0x07,0xFC,0x59,0xD7,0xFF,0x00,0x6B,0x5D,0x6F,0x4D,0xB5,0xBD,0x9F,0xE2,0x0F,0xC2,0x8B,0xED,0x37,0x4A,0xFB,0x7E,0x89,0xA5,0xAD,0xB4,0x73,0x8D,0x6A,0x4B,0xBD,0x1F,0x4D,0x8D,0xB4,0xC4,0x81,0x9E,0xDC,0x1F,0xB5,0xC7,0x22,0x4D,0x1D,0xE6,0x57,0x6F,0x97,0xE6,0x0D,0x0F,0xD9,0x9B,0xC2,0x1F,0xB4,0x77,0xC4,0x4F,0xF8,0x28,0xE7,0x8C,0x7E,0x2E,0xFC,0x59,0xF8,0xFF,0x00,0xE2,0xAF,0x10,0xF8,0x27,0xC1,0x1E,0x6E,0x83,0x6B,0xE1,0xFD,0x0B,0x48,0x6D,0x03,0xC2,0x1A,0x9E,0xB7,0xBA,0xEA,0x2D,0x4A,0xD2,0xDA,0xDD,0xA5,0xF3,0x35,0x0B,0x3D,0x36,0x46,0x30,0x25,0xEC,0xF0,0xAC,0x93,0xCC,0xA3,0xE7,0x22,0xD0,0xEF,0xFA,0xBF,0xE2,0x7F,0xED,0x5F,0xF0,0x4B,0xE1,0x57,0xC4,0xC1,0xF0,0xFB,0x53,0xF1,0x1D,0xD7,0x8B,0xBE,0x2C,0x4D,0x6B,0x71,0x35,0x8F,0xC3,0xEF,0x05,0x69,0x33,0xEB,0xBA,0xFD,0xD3,0x43,0x6C,0x2E,0xBC,0x9F,0xB2,0xDA,0xAB,0x79,0x0E,0xF1,0x32,0xBA,0x7D,0xA0,0xC4,0xAC,0xB9,0x6D,0xDB,0x55,0x99,0x79,0xF9,0xEF,0x3F,0x6C,0x0F,0x89,0x5A,0x75,0xD4,0x7A,0x3E,0x93,0xE0,0xAF,0xD9,0x8B,0x44,0xB8,0xB5,0xD4,0x61,0x82,0xF7,0x5E,0x63,0xE3,0x0F,0x12,0x46,0xDE,0x68,0x8A,0xCA,0x6F,0xB2,0x5B,0xBC,0x1A,0x7D,0xAB,0xF9,0x62,0x49,0xCF,0xFA,0x55,0xF2,0xE5,0xA2,0x42,0xA7,0x0F,0x5A,0x1F,0xF0,0xC9,0xBF,0x0E,0x3C,0x41,0xE2,0x2F,0xED,0x8F,0x8C,0x5A,0xDF,0x8A,0xBF,0x68,0x8B,0xF4,0xD5,0x7F,0xB4,0x6D,0xA0,0xF8,0x8F,0xAC,0x8B,0xAD,0x22,0xDA,0x4F,0xB2,0x7D,0x91,0x76,0x68,0xD6,0xC9,0x06,0x97,0xF2,0xA1,0x90,0x87,0xFB,0x27,0x99,0xBE,0x67,0x7D,0xD9,0xC6,0x3C,0xBF,0x46,0xD7,0x3C,0x4D,0xFB,0x17,0x6A,0x3E,0x16,0xF0,0x47,0xC4,0x7F,0x12,0x5D,0x78,0xCF,0xF6,0x51,0x92,0xD6,0xC3,0x43,0xF0,0xBF,0x8F,0xF5,0x3B,0x6B,0x68,0xAF,0x7C,0x01,0x34,0x71,0x47,0x69,0x05,0x86,0xB2,0x6D,0xE2,0x8A,0x37,0xB0,0x9B,0x62,0x79,0x5A,0x8E,0xC0,0x62,0x95,0xFC,0xBB,0x9E,0x1E,0x39,0xAB,0xEE,0xFA,0x28,0xA2,0x8A,0x28,0xA2,0x8A,0x28,0xA2,0xBE,0x30,0xFD,0xB8,0x3C,0x37,0x71,0x6B,0xFB,0x30,0x68,0xDF,0x1E,0xFC,0x35,0xA2,0xDD,0x6A,0xDF,0x10,0x7E,0x09,0x6B,0xF6,0xDE,0x35,0xD2,0xD7,0x4E,0xD4,0xA2,0xD3,0x6E,0x2E,0xB4,0xF8,0x24,0x5F,0xED,0x8B,0x17,0xBA,0x65,0x2C,0xB6,0xD3,0x69,0xFF,0x00,0x68,0xF3,0x23,0x4F,0xF5,0x86,0x28,0xBE,0x59,0x31,0xE5,0xB7,0xA0,0x7E,0xCC,0x9F,0x0E,0x7C,0x1B,0xE1,0x6F,0x80,0x76,0xDF,0x10,0x74,0x3F,0x15,0x5D,0x7C,0x52,0xF1,0x5F,0xC4,0x9B,0x5B,0x4F,0x12,0x78,0x9B,0xE2,0x4E,0xAD,0x68,0x6D,0xEF,0xFC,0x54,0xD3,0x40,0x1E,0xDE,0x5F,0x28,0x81,0xF6,0x5B,0x68,0xE2,0x70,0x96,0xF6,0x40,0x05,0xB7,0x8F,0xE5,0xC6,0xED,0xEC,0xDC,0xFF,0x00,0xC4,0xFF,0x00,0x8B,0xDE,0x32,0xF1,0x97,0x8A,0x47,0xC1,0xFF,0x00,0xD9,0x8E,0x6B,0x5D,0x5B,0xC7,0x17,0x57,0x57,0x16,0x3E,0x27,0xF8,0x8A,0x6D,0x85,0xF6,0x81,0xF0,0xED,0x60,0x60,0x97,0x3E,0x7B,0x0F,0xDD,0xDC,0xEA,0xCB,0xB8,0x08,0x74,0xBD,0xDB,0xB7,0x11,0x25,0xC0,0x8E,0x11,0xFB,0xCF,0x90,0x3F,0x68,0x9F,0x13,0xF8,0x37,0xE0,0x9F,0xC0,0x3D,0x2B,0xF6,0x0A,0xFD,0x9B,0xAC,0x2D,0x7C,0x7F,0xF1,0xBB,0xE3,0x25,0xD5,0xEE,0x87,0xE2,0x3B,0xCD,0x57,0x57,0x3A,0x8D,0xFD,0x83,0x6A,0x10,0x47,0xFD,0xA3,0xAF,0x6B,0xED,0x0E,0xEB,0xA6,0xB9,0x96,0x0B,0x9F,0x3C,0x48,0xD1,0xED,0x11,0xA3,0xC9,0xFE,0xAA,0xDD,0x60,0x7E,0x7F,0xFE,0x0A,0x43,0xF0,0xF7,0x54,0xF8,0x15,0xFF,0x00,0x04,0x2B,0xF0,0x47,0x81,0x3E,0x0E,0x7C,0x41,0xB5,0xF8,0x6F,0xF0,0xFB,0xC2,0x77,0x56,0xDA,0x3E,0xAB,0xA5,0x9B,0xB6,0xD3,0xF5,0x4F,0x17,0x43,0x34,0x32,0x5B,0x34,0x01,0xED,0x8C,0x71,0xDC,0x3C,0xBE,0x74,0xF7,0x57,0x50,0x34,0x38,0x9F,0xF7,0x93,0x65,0x3C,0x92,0xB2,0xFD,0x01,0xF0,0xC3,0xF6,0xA2,0xFD,0x9A,0x7C,0x29,0xFB,0x4F,0xFC,0x30,0xF8,0x27,0xF0,0xF7,0x43,0xD0,0x3E,0x04,0x5A,0x78,0xC2,0xD7,0x52,0x7D,0x6B,0xC1,0x3A,0x97,0x83,0x1F,0xC2,0xFA,0xC6,0x9B,0xE2,0x4F,0x2F,0x48,0x92,0xC6,0xD2,0xE6,0xD7,0x64,0x69,0x1B,0xDC,0x5B,0x5C,0xDC,0x28,0x94,0x86,0x49,0xDE,0xDE,0x38,0xE1,0x99,0xC8,0xDA,0xDF,0x67,0xFC,0x4B,0xF8,0xAB,0xF0,0xE3,0xE0,0xDF,0xC2,0xCB,0xAF,0x1A,0xFC,0x51,0xF1,0x9E,0x95,0xE0,0x7F,0x0C,0xC1,0xB8,0x7D,0xB3,0x54,0xBA,0x11,0xF9,0xF2,0x08,0xDE,0x5F,0x26,0x14,0xFB,0xD3,0xCC,0x52,0x39,0x0A,0xC3,0x18,0x69,0x1B,0x69,0xDA,0xA6,0xBF,0x38,0x3E,0x2E,0x7E,0xDA,0x9F,0xB4,0x0F,0x8F,0xBF,0x68,0xED,0x23,0xF6,0x7D,0xFD,0x92,0xFE,0x0F,0xFF,0x00,0x64,0xF8,0xDB,0x5B,0xFB,0x52,0x5C,0x78,0xA3,0xE2,0x04,0xB1,0x43,0x77,0xE1,0xFB,0x68,0x8B,0x45,0x26,0xA3,0x73,0xA2,0xEE,0x37,0x3A,0x74,0x38,0x96,0xCA,0xE6,0xDE,0x6D,0x4A,0x34,0x33,0x07,0x08,0xB6,0x72,0x97,0x4D,0xDF,0x4F,0xF8,0x07,0xF6,0x76,0xB3,0xF8,0x7D,0xFF,0x00,0x09,0xAF,0xC4,0xFF,0x00,0xDA,0x37,0xE3,0x5E,0xAB,0xF1,0xE3,0xC4,0xD7,0xBE,0x15,0xBB,0xD2,0xFC,0x45,0xAB,0x78,0xD3,0xEC,0xFA,0x77,0x85,0xF4,0xDD,0x21,0xF6,0xB5,0xE4,0x70,0x69,0x4B,0xFE,0x89,0x69,0x0C,0xB1,0x5A,0xDA,0x7D,0xA4,0xB9,0x7D,0xE6,0xDB,0x7E,0x57,0x7B,0x83,0xE7,0xFE,0x0C,0x9B,0xFE,0x14,0xE7,0xC2,0xCF,0x12,0xF8,0xE7,0xF6,0x56,0xF1,0x77,0xFC,0x35,0x17,0xEC,0xF9,0xA7,0x7D,0x8A,0xCE,0x5F,0x86,0x7A,0x3F,0x8B,0xBF,0xB7,0xB5,0x0F,0x0C,0xFD,0x9A,0x38,0xD2,0xE8,0xE8,0x7A,0x83,0xCD,0x31,0x9B,0x6D,0xAF,0x90,0xE3,0x45,0x98,0x8C,0xB7,0x30,0x4D,0x16,0xF1,0x04,0xBF,0x60,0x7C,0x34,0xF8,0xAB,0xF0,0xE3,0xE3,0x27,0xC2,0xCB,0x5F,0x1A,0xFC,0x2E,0xF1,0x9E,0x95,0xE3,0x8F,0x0C,0xCF,0xB4,0x7D,0xB3,0x4B,0xBA,0x12,0x79,0x12,0x18,0xD2,0x5F,0x26,0x64,0xFB,0xD0,0x4C,0x12,0x48,0xCB,0x43,0x20,0x59,0x17,0x70,0xDC,0xA2,0xBB,0xFA,0x28,0xA2,0x8A,0x28,0xA2,0x8A,0x28,0xAF,0xCA,0x1F,0x0B,0xDC,0x7C,0x70,0xB2,0xF8,0xEB,0xE3,0x3F,0xF8,0x27,0xCF,0x81,0xAD,0xBC,0x55,0xE0,0xAF,0x01,0x78,0x73,0x55,0x86,0xF2,0xCB,0xE2,0xFD,0x8D,0xB4,0xCD,0x36,0x8F,0xE0,0x6B,0xD8,0x6E,0x2E,0x53,0x4E,0xB6,0xB8,0xBC,0xB8,0x72,0xB7,0x91,0x4F,0xB7,0x48,0xB5,0xBB,0x4F,0x3B,0xF7,0x50,0xCE,0xE2,0x28,0xDE,0xC8,0x9A,0xF5,0xF7,0xF1,0x9F,0x8A,0x46,0xB1,0xAB,0xFE,0xCD,0x3F,0xB1,0x47,0x86,0xB7,0xD8,0x68,0x9A,0xAD,0xDD,0x97,0x8E,0x3E,0x30,0x78,0x87,0x5A,0x93,0x54,0xD3,0x7C,0x11,0xA9,0xDE,0x5C,0x3D,0xED,0xD8,0x5F,0xB5,0xBC,0x93,0x6B,0x7A,0x98,0x32,0xDC,0x3B,0xC5,0xE6,0x6C,0x86,0x79,0xED,0x84,0xED,0x86,0x91,0x13,0xA0,0xD4,0xBF,0x66,0x6B,0x3F,0x84,0xB7,0x5F,0x00,0x3C,0x53,0xF0,0x9B,0x4F,0xF1,0x57,0x8C,0x3F,0xE1,0x5D,0x78,0xAB,0x55,0xD6,0xBC,0x4D,0xA1,0xA6,0xBD,0x6E,0xDA,0x97,0x8E,0x2E,0x75,0x5D,0x2E,0xE2,0xCA,0xE3,0x56,0xBC,0x92,0xF1,0xE1,0x8A,0xEF,0x53,0x13,0x4B,0x13,0xF9,0xD3,0x4F,0x10,0x58,0x1A,0xED,0x23,0xFF,0x00,0x96,0x50,0xD7,0xCE,0x1F,0xB5,0x5F,0xC2,0x3B,0x8F,0x8B,0x9F,0xB2,0x47,0xC4,0x3F,0x8A,0x7F,0xB6,0x6F,0x8A,0xFC,0x15,0xF0,0x2A,0x45,0xF0,0x54,0xBA,0x67,0xC2,0xBF,0x0A,0xFF,0x00,0x6C,0x45,0x79,0x0F,0x86,0x75,0x09,0x12,0xDF,0x52,0x9A,0x4B,0x8D,0x41,0xAD,0x0C,0xD7,0x97,0xF3,0x4D,0xA7,0x2D,0xBB,0x43,0x61,0x11,0xC5,0xA4,0x73,0xA4,0x3E,0x7B,0xCE,0xD2,0x56,0x87,0x88,0x7C,0x1D,0xFB,0x40,0xFE,0xDB,0x1F,0x14,0xFE,0x1D,0x78,0xE2,0xFF,0x00,0xE0,0x87,0x85,0x7E,0x08,0xFC,0x39,0xD3,0x7C,0x01,0x7F,0xA6,0x4B,0x1F,0xC7,0x0F,0x04,0xC5,0xAF,0xEA,0xF6,0x1A,0xBE,0xA1,0x20,0xFB,0x55,0xD6,0x9D,0xA6,0x3C,0xA1,0x5F,0xEC,0xEF,0xA6,0xD9,0xAC,0x32,0xDF,0x47,0x6D,0x94,0xB8,0x99,0xFC,0xA9,0x95,0xC2,0x0F,0x9F,0xFE,0x32,0x68,0x7F,0xB2,0xA7,0xEC,0x65,0xFB,0x53,0x78,0x7B,0xE0,0xE6,0x8D,0xAA,0xFF,0x00,0xC2,0x98,0xF1,0x7F,0x8B,0xB4,0xA9,0x7C,0x4B,0xE3,0x4F,0x8E,0xD7,0xBA,0x1F,0xDB,0xB5,0xED,0x3F,0x4E,0x9E,0xE6,0xEE,0x0F,0xB0,0x78,0x7A,0x1B,0x0B,0x53,0x0E,0x99,0x79,0x38,0x6B,0x98,0x3C,0xE8,0x2D,0xAD,0xA1,0x82,0xD9,0x41,0x02,0x69,0x7C,0xB0,0x9F,0x60,0x59,0x7C,0x4D,0xF1,0x4F,0xC3,0xFF,0x00,0x85,0x9E,0x39,0xF0,0x37,0xEC,0x53,0xFB,0x1A,0x78,0xFF,0x00,0xC4,0xFA,0xB4,0x5A,0xAB,0xEA,0x37,0x5E,0x20,0xF8,0x86,0x92,0x78,0x67,0x4F,0xD4,0xEF,0x75,0x08,0xE4,0x96,0x4D,0x46,0x4B,0x8D,0x6E,0x68,0xF5,0x2D,0x56,0x65,0x9C,0x22,0x4A,0xAE,0x15,0xB6,0xAE,0x3C,0xE4,0x5F,0x27,0x77,0xCB,0xFA,0x67,0xEC,0xE1,0xFB,0x6A,0xFE,0xD3,0xFF,0x00,0xB6,0x4F,0x8A,0x35,0x6F,0x8F,0x1E,0x3D,0xD2,0xB4,0x2F,0x08,0x78,0x1F,0xED,0x9A,0x75,0x95,0xAE,0xBB,0xE1,0x09,0x35,0x9F,0x08,0x6A,0xBA,0xBC,0xAB,0x76,0x89,0x73,0xA5,0x68,0x37,0x90,0xD9,0x09,0x61,0xB2,0x82,0xFF,0x00,0x62,0x5F,0x5E,0x7D,0xA7,0x7C,0xD6,0xEA,0x56,0x5B,0xB8,0x89,0x58,0xBF,0x43,0xFC,0x15,0xF0,0x3B,0xF6,0x83,0xB1,0xF0,0xB4,0xF1,0x7C,0x45,0xFD,0xB5,0xBC,0x6B,0xE2,0x9D,0x6C,0xDD,0x16,0x86,0xEB,0xC3,0x9E,0x03,0xF0,0xBE,0x8D,0x6E,0x90,0xED,0x5C,0x21,0x86,0x6D,0x3E,0xED,0x99,0xF7,0x6F,0x3B,0xFC,0xC0,0x30,0x40,0xDA,0x31,0x96,0xD0,0xF0,0x37,0xEC,0xC7,0x07,0x82,0x3F,0x6C,0x9D,0x53,0xE3,0x87,0xFC,0x2E,0x7F,0x1F,0xF8,0x93,0xC5,0xBA,0xC6,0x95,0x1E,0x9B,0xE2,0x3B,0x4B,0xF8,0xF4,0x3B,0x6D,0x3F,0x5E,0x8A,0x15,0x61,0x6E,0xD7,0x90,0xD9,0x69,0x96,0xFE,0x6C,0xD0,0xEE,0xFD,0xDD,0xC6,0x44,0xAA,0xA3,0xCB,0xDF,0xE5,0x66,0x33,0xF4,0xFD,0x14,0x51,0x45,0x14,0x51,0x45,0x14,0x57,0xCE,0x1F,0x15,0xFF,0x00,0x65,0xDF,0x87,0x9F,0x19,0x3E,0x32,0x5A,0x78,0xBF,0xC5,0x5A,0xE7,0x8D,0x74,0xE8,0xE4,0xD0,0x1F,0x40,0xF1,0x26,0x81,0xE1,0xCF,0x19,0xDE,0x69,0x3A,0x5F,0x8A,0xF4,0xFC,0x4F,0xE5,0x5B,0x6A,0x51,0x5B,0xBA,0xB4,0xA9,0x0B,0x5D,0xDD,0x32,0x6C,0x64,0xCF,0x9E,0xE1,0xFC,0xC4,0xF9,0x2B,0xDC,0x3C,0x2F,0xE1,0x3F,0x0B,0x78,0x1F,0xC0,0xB6,0x3E,0x17,0xF0,0x57,0x86,0xB4,0xAF,0x07,0xF8,0x66,0xCB,0x7F,0xD8,0xF4,0x8D,0x13,0x4F,0x8E,0xCE,0xD2,0xDF,0x7B,0x99,0x1F,0x64,0x51,0x80,0xAB,0x97,0x66,0x63,0x81,0xC9,0x62,0x6B,0xE1,0xFF,0x00,0xDA,0x1B,0xF6,0xF9,0xF8,0x71,0xF0,0xBB,0xFE,0x12,0x9F,0x07,0xF8,0x0B,0x50,0xD2,0xBC,0x47,0xF1,0x1B,0x4F,0xFB,0x75,0xA4,0xBA,0xA6,0xBB,0x78,0x2C,0x3C,0x2F,0xA2,0xDE,0x5A,0x7D,0x93,0xED,0x49,0x73,0x76,0xEC,0xAD,0x7F,0x35,0xBA,0x5F,0x47,0x23,0xE9,0xFA,0x62,0xDD,0x5E,0x12,0x86,0x2D,0x91,0xB3,0x03,0x5E,0x41,0xA4,0xF8,0x6F,0xE2,0x9F,0x8C,0xFE,0x3A,0x9F,0x1A,0x69,0x1F,0x03,0xF5,0x5F,0xDA,0x1B,0xE2,0x64,0x3A,0xAE,0xA4,0xDA,0x6F,0xC5,0x4F,0x8E,0x50,0xDC,0xF8,0x37,0xC2,0x1E,0x0B,0xB8,0x30,0xDA,0x5C,0xD9,0x0D,0x13,0xC3,0x17,0x3E,0x7D,0xEA,0x43,0x1B,0x41,0x6F,0x13,0x5C,0x2C,0x09,0x70,0xF3,0x44,0xE7,0xED,0x6C,0x1D,0xDE,0x2F,0xA7,0xE4,0xF8,0x11,0xF1,0xC3,0xE2,0x6F,0xFC,0x23,0xF7,0xBF,0x1D,0x3F,0x68,0xBD,0x57,0x41,0x86,0xCF,0xFB,0x3E,0xEE,0x5F,0x09,0x7C,0x12,0x8E,0x6F,0x0A,0xE9,0xF2,0x5C,0xC5,0xE6,0x9B,0xA8,0xEE,0x35,0x07,0x96,0x6D,0x42,0xEA,0x19,0x3C,0xD1,0x17,0xEE,0xE5,0xB4,0x1B,0x62,0x0F,0xE5,0xAC,0x98,0x64,0xF6,0x0F,0x83,0xBF,0x00,0xBE,0x0D,0xFE,0xCF,0xFE,0x05,0x97,0xC3,0xBF,0x07,0xBE,0x1E,0xE9,0x5E,0x07,0xB0,0x9F,0x1F,0x6C,0x96,0xD1,0x1A,0x4B,0xBB,0xDC,0x3C,0x8E,0x9F,0x68,0xBA,0x90,0xB4,0xD3,0xEC,0x33,0x49,0xB3,0xCC,0x76,0xD8,0x1B,0x6A,0xE0,0x71,0x5E,0xBF,0x45,0x14,0x51,0x45,0x14,0x51,0x45,0x14,0x51,0x45,0x14,0x57,0xE5,0x0F,0xED,0x6F,0xE3,0x2F,0x1D,0x7C,0x52,0xFF,0x00,0x82,0xC9,0x7C,0x1E,0xFD,0x86,0x1F,0xC6,0xFA,0xAF,0x81,0x3E,0x09,0xFC,0x43,0xF0,0x05,0xE5,0xFF,0x00,0x8C,0x25,0xF0,0xAF,0x93,0x06,0xAF,0xA8,0xFE,0xEF,0x51,0x7F,0x23,0xED,0x53,0x47,0x2E,0xC8,0x7F,0xE2,0x5B,0x1A,0x94,0x45,0x5D,0xE9,0x3C,0xE9,0x26,0xF5,0x60,0x17,0xED,0xFF,0x00,0x85,0xDF,0xB2,0xAF,0xEC,0xE3,0xF0,0x5F,0xFB,0x0E,0x6F,0x86,0x9F,0x06,0x3C,0x2B,0xE1,0xBD,0x5B,0x47,0xF3,0xBF,0xB3,0xB5,0xCF,0xEC,0xB5,0xB9,0xD5,0xE1,0xF3,0xB7,0xF9,0x9F,0xE9,0xF3,0x6F,0xB9,0x39,0x12,0xBA,0x73,0x21,0xF9,0x0E,0xCF,0xBB,0xC5,0x7B,0xFD,0x14,0x51,0x45,0x14,0x51,0x45,0x14,0x51,0x5F,0xFF,0xD9
```

Comment: if (str[s] == 1) -> Have a look what str is at that point. This can't work.

You should learn to use the debugger. str[s] will never be 1 - maybe you wan't to compare to '1' . You will also never get the desired result because you only add 0 and 255 to your result.

Comment: i forgot to add '1'. but  i try the code in java it  works.

Comment: This can never work because you only add 0 and 255. How should there be the value (for example) 0xD8 if you only add 0x00 and 0xFF?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to do here, but the reason for the error is down to this line here:

```
for (byte s = 0; s < 8; s++)
```

It assumes that the string *str* is always *eight* characters long.  This will prevent the error.

```
for (byte s = 0; s < str.Length; s++)
```

But it may not give you the output you are after..?

Answer (score 0):

Your program breaks at the line:

```
if (str[s] == '1')
```

At this line, `str` == 255.  The loop tries to iterate through 8 places in a string containing 3.  Therefore, when it hit index 3, it becomes out of bounds (we always start at 0).

Your 3rd and most inner `for` loop should be:

```
for (byte s = 0; s < str.Length; s++;)
{
    if (str[s] == '1')
        signdecompress[ByteIndex + s] = (byte)255;
    else 
        signdecompress[ByteIndex + s] = (byte)0;
}
```

Iterating based on the `Length` of the `string` or `Count` of something is always best practice, unless you know definitively that you will always only have a given number of indices.